# websockets and WebContainer HttpSession in glassfish V3.1.2.2 and grizzly-websockets v1.9.56

Tags: websocket, glassfish-3, httpsession

Problem : **Websockets and WebContainer HttpSession**  in glassfish V3.1.2.2 and grizzly-websockets v1.9.56.

ref link : http://java.net/jira/browse/GRIZZLY-1289

i am use web-scoket with glassfish server. so webscoket use glassfish V3.1.2.2 and grizzly-websockets v1.9.56 .

and i completed create webscoket and use this our application . but i get one problem like:

i use session and i get session using "DefaultWebSocket" of webscoket. but i did not get current session (i get new or null not current ) .

code :

```
@Override
    public WebSocket createWebSocket(ProtocolHandler protocolHandler,
            final WebSocketListener... listeners) {

DefaultWebSocket defaultWebSocket = new DefaultWebSocket(protocolHandler,listeners);

HttpSession httpSession = defaultWebSocket.getRequest().getSession(false);

return defaultWebSocket ;
}
```

"httpSession" object is null or new Not current .

help me.

Answer (score 2):

download glassfish 3.1.2.2, patch it w/ the grizzly-websockets-1.9.50.jar (download for   [java.net/jira/browse/GRIZZLY-1289](http://java.net/jira/browse/GRIZZLY-1289)) like
$cp ./grizzly-websockets-1.9.50-fix.jar glassfish3/glassfish/modules/grizzly-websockets.jar

start glassfish 3.1.2.2
$glassfish3/bin/asadmin start-domain

enable websockets for http-listener-1
$glassfish3/bin/asadmin set configs.config.server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-1.http.websockets-support-enabled=true

then run your app in a browser.

Thanks,